# how to set color to tab in android?

Tags: android

I am trying below code but not work properly

```
public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //unselected
    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
}
```

I want change my default color of tab.

Thank in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577688/android-change-tab-text-color-programmatically?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
{
    RelativeLayout tv = (RelativeLayout ) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setBackgroungColor(.....);
}
```

Just use like this...hopes it works

Comment: I want background color not text color

Comment: @ Kiran Mane u just used Relative layout id's from there

Comment: i need only set background to tab not text view or title