# Using TabHost how do I change text colour?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm using TabHost in my code and I am wondering how I can change the text colour? I thought it would be something to do with the XML but upon looking at it I don't think it is:

```
public class HealthyEating extends TabActivity{
Resources res;
TabHost tabHost;
Intent intent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_healthy_eating);

    res = getResources();
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BreakfastRecipe.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Breakfast Recipes").setIndicator("Breakfast Recipes")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LunchRecipe.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Lunch Recipes").setIndicator("Lunch Recipes")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it through the tabs title `TextView`. For details see:

[Android: Change Tab Text Color Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577688/android-change-tab-text-color-programmatically)

Example usage for you having a text color of red would be:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.myproject.R;

public class HealthyEating extends TabActivity {
    Resources res;
    TabHost tabHost;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_healthy_eating);

        res = getResources();
        tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BreakfastRecipe.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Breakfast Recipes").setIndicator("Breakfast Recipes")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LunchRecipe.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Lunch Recipes").setIndicator("Lunch Recipes")
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        int titleColor = Color.RED; //<-- change this to the color you want the title text to be
        for(int i = 0;i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            TextView textView = (TextView)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            textView.setTextColor(titleColor);
        }
    }
}
```

The `for` loop goes through each of the tabs that you've added to the `TabHost` and accesses the `TextView` that is associated with the title label. The `setTextColor` method is used to change the text color to what you want (in this example red). It may be worthwhile checking out the docs for [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html).

Note in particular the extra import statements that you will need: `import android.widget.TextView` and `import android.graphics.Color`

This example worked for me with the following `activity_healthy_eating` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

If you're getting any errors please post them and I'll try to address them.

More information on `Color` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)) in Android can be found [here](http://android4beginners.com/2013/06/appendix-b-everything-about-colors-in-android/)

An online tool for finding the hex color code you're after can found [here](http://www.color-hex.com).

Comment: Pretty new to java, I tried to implement that and it really didn't make much sense to me I'm afraid :/

Comment: You should be able to copy/paste from the code in my edited answer. If that doesn't work, let me know what the issue is and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt    (i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```