# How to change selected Tab Text color using TabLayout from code in Android?

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-tablayout

> [image]

I'm using `android.support.widget.TabLayout` to make a Tab view, and I want to change the selected tabs text color from code (not from xml or by styling). How can I do this ?

Comment: its android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577688/android-change-tab-text-color-programmatically

Comment: actually i m asking using TabLayout not TabHost

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you are using the design support library add this code to your *tab activity*.

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#727272"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

This will set the *tab text color* as well as tab indicator color in your tab activity.

Comment: thank  you help but i m asking to change the text color of current  tab

Comment: yes the third line's first parameter is for the default color and the second parameter will set the mentioned color to the selected tab. ie for the non-selected tab the color will be #727272 and for selected tab the color will be #ffffff

Comment: if you can please accept the answer. glad this helped you

Comment: not working. I tried with creating style also but none worked

Answer (score 125):

It's so simple using XML. Just add the following 2 attributes in your tab layout.

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_primary_text"
app:tabTextColor="@color/color_secondary_text"
```

So, your code would look something like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/button_background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/fixed_bottom_button"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_primary_text"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_primary_text"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/color_secondary_text" />
```

Comment: @Raykud Yeah, you are right. But at that time, I was looking for a solution using XML and didn't found any. So, I posted my solution for anyone looking for the same in the future.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the simplest solution

Comment: @inspire_coding I acknowledge your appreciation. But the OP want to change the tab colour from code, i.e. `.java` or `.kt` file.

Comment: @inspire_coding no doubt it's a simple and quick one, but I needed (at that time)  to add color from java code, So the accepted answer would be the one given by - Shaan_B

Answer (score 21):

Please check out following answer

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            View view = tab.getCustomView();
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_background);
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
            TypefacedTextView selectedText = (TypefacedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tab_name);
            selectedText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            View view = tab.getCustomView();
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_background);
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
            TypefacedTextView selectedText = (TypefacedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tab_name);
            selectedText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

where tabLayout is object of TabLayout Class

Comment: This variant suits better if you have a custom view for tab item.

Answer (score 11):

It's better if you update the library with "`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`". Then use bellow code,

**In XML attributes**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabBackground="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

**In Kotlin programmatically**

```
(tab_layout as TabLayout).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary))
(tab_layout as TabLayout).setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white))
(tab_layout as TabLayout).setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white),
                ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white))
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this might be a bit late but here is more simpler code :

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_200), getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

first value is the default text color, 2nd value is the selected tab text color.

Comment: Might be useful for anyone who is looking for the same issue :)

Comment: thanks, buddy what exactly i'm looking for <3 :*

Answer (score 3):

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#727272"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write it in xml

```
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/my_color"
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Using native android code you can chage multiple tab background & text color

```
LinearLayout tabsContainer = (LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= selectedTab.size(); j++) {
                if (selectedTab.contains(section)) {
                    LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) tabsContainer.getChildAt(section - 1);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) item.getChildAt(1);
                    item.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color00DF4C));
                    tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Copy these two files :

1. SlidingTabLayout.java :

package com.some.package;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * To be used with ViewPager to provide a tab indicator component which give constant feedback as to
 * the user's scroll progress.
 * <p>
 * To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your
 * {@link android.app.Activity} or {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} call
 * {@link #setViewPager(ViewPager)} providing it the ViewPager this layout is being used for.
 * <p>
 * The colors can be customized in two ways. The first and simplest is to provide an array of colors
 * via {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)}. The
 * alternative is via the {@link TabColorizer} interface which provides you complete control over
 * which color is used for any individual position.
 * <p>
 * The views used as tabs can be customized by calling {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)},
 * providing the layout ID of your custom layout.
 */
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_SIDE_PADDING_DIPS = 18;

    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;
    Context mContext;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     *
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {

            InternalViewPagerListener listener = new InternalViewPagerListener();
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(listener);
            populateTabStrip();
            listener.onPageSelected(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        Typeface typeFace;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            typeFace = //set your typeface here
        }else{
            typeFace = //set your typeface here
        }

        TextView textView= new TextView(context);

        textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.inactive_tab_color));
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        int sidePadding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_SIDE_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(sidePadding, padding, sidePadding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);

            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            ((TextView) selectedTitle).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            int remainingTabs = mTabStrip.getChildCount() - position;
            for(int i=0 ;i< mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++){
                if(i == position)
                    continue;

                View remainingTitles = mTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
                ((TextView) remainingTitles).setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.inactive_tab_color));
            }

        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

2. SlidingTabStrip.java :

   package com.some.package;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.graphics.Canvas;
   import android.graphics.Color;
   import android.graphics.Paint;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.util.TypedValue;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;

   class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

   ```
   private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
   private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
   private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 2;
   private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

   private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
   private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

   private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
   private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

   private int mSelectedPosition;
   private float mSelectionOffset;

   private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
   private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

   SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
       this(context, null);
   }

   SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       setWillNotDraw(false);

       final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

       TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
       context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
       final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

       int defaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
               DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

       mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
       mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

       mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
       mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
       mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(defaultBottomBorderColor);

       mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
       mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
   }

   void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
       mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
       invalidate();
   }

   void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
       // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
       mCustomTabColorizer = null;
       mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
       invalidate();
   }

   void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
       mSelectedPosition = position;
       mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
       invalidate();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       final int height = getHeight();
       final int childCount = getChildCount();
       final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
               ? mCustomTabColorizer
               : mDefaultTabColorizer;

       // Thick colored underline below the current selection
       if (childCount > 0) {
           View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
           int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
           int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
           int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

           if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
               int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
               if (color != nextColor) {
                   color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
               }

               // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
               View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
               left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                       (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
               right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                       (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
           }

           mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

           canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                   height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
       }

       // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
       canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);

   }

   /**
    * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
    */
   private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
       return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
   }

   /**
    * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
    *
    * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
    *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
    */
   private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
       final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
       float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
       float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
       float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
       return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
   }

   private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
       private int[] mIndicatorColors;

       @Override
       public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
           return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
       }

       void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
           mIndicatorColors = colors;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

I haven't written these above two files. I took it from the official android documentation site.

Now take the widget SlidingTabLayout in your layout xml file.

and finally add this code to your Activity/Fragment :

CONTENT = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D"};

```
mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
SlidingTabsAdapter adapter =new SlidingTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(someColorID));
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);
```

private class SlidingTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
public SlidingTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;
    Bundle b;

    switch (position){

        case 0:

            fragment = new FragmentA();

        break;

        case 1:

            fragment = new FragmentB();

        break;

        case 2:

            fragment = new FragmentC();

        break;

        case 3:

            fragment = new FragmentD();

        break;

        default:

            fragment = new FragmentZ();

    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return CONTENT.length;
}
```

}