# Android TabLayout With Text and Icons Change color of both text and Icon on selected tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout

In my app implementing tablayout with each tab having both icons and text.
When tab is selected then icon and text should be selected of same tab and 
un-selected tab with different color text and icons.

below is my code to implement tabs layout but not able to change  text color and icons color on tab selection.

```
private void setupTabIcons() {

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custome_tab_with_icon, null);
    tabOne.setText("Home");
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.selector_home, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custome_tab_with_icon, null);
    tabTwo.setText("Search");
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.selector_search, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

    TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custome_tab_with_icon, null);
    tabThree.setText("WishList");
    tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.selector_wishlist, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

    TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custome_tab_with_icon, null);
    tabFour.setText("Cart");
    tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.selector_cart, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);

    TextView tabFive = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custome_tab_with_icon, null);
    tabFive.setText("Account");
    tabFive.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.selector_accounts, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setCustomView(tabFive);

}
```

Please help how to change text color and icon when tab is selected.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

**Toggle tab text color** 
In your xml add the lines`app:tabTextColor` and `app:tabSelectedTextColor` to the TabLayout .

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:tabTextColor="#000000"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Toggle tab icon** In your fargment/activity add selector drawable to each tab.

```
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        //Set selector drawable to each tab
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Warm Up").setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.selector_warmup_icon,null)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Exercise").setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.selector_exercise_icon, null)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Rest").setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.selector_rest_icon, null)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Success").setIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.selector_success_icon, null)));
```

selector_warmup_icon.xml (should be like)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_human_white_48dp" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_human_grey600_24dp" android:state_selected="false"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Nothing is display on tablayout. after applying above code tab bar is blank no icon no text.

Comment: Use .setText("Tab name") to give the tab name.Check the updated code now the text will appear as far as icons are concerned check the selector file properly

Comment: This doesn't work properly for kit kat as All tabs have same color and that's the color for the unselected tab

Comment: this might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61884583/8889086 @John

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` and it has three methods `onTabSelected()`, `onTabUnselected()` and `onTabReselected()`, which you can use to change the color of both icon and text. Here's the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html) you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Color State List resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for the text color as well as for the tint of the icons. I think `android:state_selected` should work.