# Having lower case title in TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I've implemented `Tabhost` from following code, the title seems to be in uppercase by default. How to place a lowercase title in the `Tabhost` ?

Here's my code for `Tabhost` implementation.

```
TabHost tabHost =getTabHost() ;

      // Tab for public
       TabHost.TabSpec publiComp = tabHost.newTabSpec("Public");
       publiComp.setIndicator("Public");
       Intent publicIntent = new Intent(this, CompliancePublic.class);
       publiComp.setContent(publicIntent);

       // Tab for private
       TabHost.TabSpec privateComp = tabHost.newTabSpec("Private");
       privateComp.setIndicator("Private");
       Intent privateIntent = new Intent(this, CompliancePrivate.class);
       privateComp.setContent(privateIntent);

       tabHost.addTab(publiComp);
       tabHost.addTab(privateComp);
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40929033/5209766

Comment: Is the procedure same for tabhost and tablayout? @SuryaPrakashKushawah

Comment: try to use your custom view for `TabHost`

Comment: Can you elaborate with examples ?? @Logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

View tabIndicatorToday = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
        ((TextView) tabIndicatorToday.findViewById(R.id.tv_tab_txt)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.text));

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.text)).setIndicator(tabIndicatorToday), Fragment.class, null);
```

and give your own style to your `TextView`